# Center navigation bar with CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to center my nav bar. I checked my sites but nothing works
and I'm completely stumped as to why it won't center, here is my navigation bar HTML that I want to center:

```
<div class='nav'>
<ul class='menu' id='menu'>
<li><a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>home</a></li>
<li><a class='drop-ctg' href='#'>PORTFOLIO</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href='http://effectsforshare.blogspot.com/p/trailer.html'>TRAILER</a></li>
     <li><a href='http://effectsforshare.blogspot.com/p/motion-graphics.html'>MOTION GRAPHICS</a></li>
     <li><a href='http://effectsforshare.blogspot.com/p/trapcode-particular.html'>TRAPCODE PARTICULAR</a></li>

   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='http://effectsforshare.blogspot.com/'>TEMPLATES</a></li>
<li><a href='http://effectsforshare.blogspot.com/p/my-blog.html'>MY BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href='http://effectsforshare.blogspot.com/p/contact-me.html'>CONTACT ME</a></li>


</ul>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  outline:0;
}
.nav {
  width:950px;
  height:auto;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  margin:10px auto 5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.menu {
  width:auto;
  list-style:none;
  font:$pagenavifont;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.menu a {
  float:left;
  color:#999;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  width:auto;
  line-height:36px;
  padding:0 20px;
}
.menu a:hover,li.menuhover a{
  color:#111;
}
.menu li {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:auto;
}
.menu li:last-child {
  background:none;
}
.menu ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:36px;
  left:0;
  background:#fbfbfb;
  display:none;
  list-style:none;
}
.menu ul li{
  float:none;
  border-top:1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-right:1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-left:1px solid #e3e3e3;
  width:auto;
  background:none;
}
.menu ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom:1px solid #e3e3e3
}
.menu ul li a{
  float:none;
  display:block;
  background:none;
  line-height:36px;
  min-width:137px;
  width:auto;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left:10px;
  color:#444;
}

.menu ul li a:hover{
  background:#fdfdfd;
  color:#777;
}
```

I would give you a link to the page but it's being done in Dreamweaver and is not up yet. The `logobar.jpg` is the logo for the webpage. I love how it looks, but it needs to be centered and not be cut off or taken to the next line when I shrink my screensize.

I tried each of `float: right`, `float: left`, and `float: none` on almost all of the classes; `text-align: center` on each class on the html side; I have tried `align=center` on each class; `display: inline`, `inline-block` on `ul` and `li` classes.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `.menu` class, you do have `text-align:center` set.  We can certainly use that to center the child nodes.

So within your `.menu li` css property, add `display:inline-block` and remove the floats.  This will center your list items.

**See the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/RGREA/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
div.nav{margin: 3px auto;}
</style>
```